# Javascript Box Shadow

Tags: javascript, css

I have a box that previews a Box Shadow. The user types in the inputs for the lenghts, blur, spread and colour (hex). So far I have this for the output of the style but it obviously doesn't work.

```
document.getElementById('jj_preview3').style["boxShadow"] = jj_input6 + 'px' + jj_input7 + 'px' + jj_input8 + 'px' + jj_input9 + '#' + jj_input10;
```

- `jj_input6` = Horizontal Length
- `jj_input7` = Vertical Length
- `jj_input8` = Blue Radius
- `jj_input9` = Spread
- `jj_input10` = Shadow Colour

What changes do I have to make the the javascript code snippet above to make it work?

Comment: You're missing spaces, for one thing. AFAIK, `3px2px3px2px#ff0000` is not a valid `box-shadow` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work if you put in spaces. You're also missing 'px' in the last string literal.

```
document.getElementById('jj_preview3').style['boxShadow'] = jj_input6 + 'px ' + 
    jj_input7 + 'px ' + jj_input8 + 'px ' + jj_input9 + 'px #' + jj_input10;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply for future references:

```
 var someVariable = document.getElementById("someId")
 someVariable.style.boxShadow = "5px 5px 1.2em black";
```

Note: The **1.2em** is for the blur effect, but **px** could be used as well, or it can be omitted all together.